# Program that reads several lengths in inches and, for each, converts it to yards, feet and inches

Tags: c

write a C program that reads several lengths in inches and, for each, converts it to
yards, feet and inches. (1 yard = 3 feet, 1 foot = 12 inches). For example, if a length
is 100, the program should print 2 yd 2 ft 4 in. Choose an appropriate end-
of-data marker.

I am unable to inter-prate the question, especially the example that has been provided.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what Stack Overflow is, it's a Q&A site, not a free homework solving service.
Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and then edit your question to include a clear explanation of the problem, what you have tried, and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to inter-prate the question, especially the example that has been provided.

I'd interpret the software's requirements as:

- get numbers from the user (until they enter an appropriate "end of data marker" to quit your program). The numbers from the user represent lengths in inches. I'd assume you should print some kind of prompt for this (like maybe "`Enter next number (or 'q' to exit):`").
- for each number from the user, convert "inches only" into "yards, feet and inches". I'd assume this needs to be displayed so the user can see the answer.

For the provided example; there's 12 inches per foot so 100 inches would be 8.3333.. feet, or 8 feet and 4 inches; and there's 3 feet per yard so 8 feet would be 2 yards and 2 feet; so the final answer is "2 yards, 2 feet, 4 inches".

For a larger example; if the user entered "`13`", then "`100`", then "`q`", the full transcript might be like:

```
Enter next number (or 'q' to exit):
13
0 yards, 1 feet, 1 inches

Enter next number (or 'q' to exit):
100
2 yards, 2 feet, 4 inches

Enter next number (or 'q' to exit):
q
```